# Exporting a VARCHAR(MAX) Field from SQL to Excel in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm creating a SSIS Package to export Data from a SQL Server Table into an Excel Sheet. My Table has one column of datatype `VARCHAR(MAX)`. And this column can have data as big as 30,000 characters sometimes. So I used a Data Conversion block to convert that column's DataType from it's original datatype `text stream [DT_TEXT]` to `Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]`. But when I execute the Package, I get this error **An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "MyColumnName" column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT"**.

I googled a lot but I couldn't get an answer to my problem. I'd appreciate all the help that I could get.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the data conversion task and just force the type when you extract from SQL Server `SELECT CAST(MyBigColumn AS nvarchar(max)) As MyBigColumnUnicode` but you're going to run into the problem that a cell in Excel cannot hold 100k characters.

> Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,776

[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Should I be adding that on the OLEDBSource -or- on the ExcelDestination? I tried on the OLEDBSource but the error still exists.